# Why is Thymeleaf only showing the last line of the list?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to get each value from the `listAppointments` and add it to `appointments`. Now I want to add each of that value to a `model` but Thymeleaf is showing only the last value. What should I do?

```
@GetMapping("/appointmenttoday")
public String appointmentToday(Model model) {
       ZoneId defaultZoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
       LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
       List<Appointments> listAppointments = appointmentsRepository.findAll();
       for(int i = 0; i < listAppointments.size(); i++) {
           Appointments appointments = listAppointments.get(i);
           LocalDate currentDate1 = appointments.toDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
           if(currentDate.compareTo(currentDate1) == 0) {
                model.addAttribute("listAppointments", appointments);
           }
       }
        
return "appointmenttoday";
}
```

Thymeleaf:

```
<tbody> 
    <tr th:each="appointment: ${listAppointments}">
        <td th:text="${appointment.appointmentNumber}">Appointment Number</td>
    </tr>
<tbody>
```

Comment: And where your view(Thymeleaf)? and you have to add more details about question

Comment: <tbody>
                <tr th:each="appointment: ${listAppointments}">
                  
                    <td th:text="${appointment.appointmentNumber}">Appointment Number</td>

Comment: why you don't put `listAppointments` directly in model and iterate in thymeleaf

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the `listAppointments` **model attribute** over and over again as a single `Appointments` object. You should make a new list and then add the desired elements to that list and then you should put that list to model.

```
@GetMapping("/appointmenttoday")
public String appointmentToday(Model model) {
    ZoneId defaultZoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
    List<Appointments> listAppointments = appointmentsRepository.findAll();
    List<Appointments> result = new List<Appointments>();
    for(int i = 0; i < listAppointments.size(); i++) {
        Appointments appointments = listAppointments.get(i);
        LocalDate currentDate1 = appointments.toDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        if(currentDate.compareTo(currentDate1) == 0) {
           result.add(appointments);
        }
    }

    model.addAttribute("listAppointments", result);        
    return "appointmenttoday";
}
```

Comment: You can also do the same thing with removing the undesired appointments from the original list and then adding that list to the model.